# Why is array.min so slow?

Tags: ruby, performance, min, built-in

I noticed that `array.min` seems slow, so I did this test against my own naive implementation:

```
require 'benchmark'
array = (1..100000).to_a.shuffle

Benchmark.bmbm(5) do |x|
  x.report("lib:") { 99.times { min = array.min } }
  x.report("own:") { 99.times { min = array[0]; array.each { |n| min = n if n < min } } }
end
```

The results:

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
lib:    1.531000   0.000000   1.531000 (  1.538159)
own:    1.094000   0.016000   1.110000 (  1.102130)
-------------------------------- total: 2.641000sec

            user     system      total        real
lib:    1.500000   0.000000   1.500000 (  1.515249)
own:    1.125000   0.000000   1.125000 (  1.145894)
```

I'm shocked. How can my own implementation running a block via `each` beat the built-in? And beat it by so much?

Am I somehow mistaken? Or is this somehow normal? I'm confused.

---

My Ruby version, running on Windows 8.1 Pro:

```
C:\>ruby --version
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [i386-mingw32]
```

Comment: My results are quite different https://gist.github.com/weppos/3411eafc2c52e69ec751

Comment: So they're about equally fast for you. Still surprises me. What version do you have? I have 2.2.2p95, will update to 2.3 now and test again.

Comment: Meant 2.2.3 of course. Did that now, but I still observe the same thing.

Comment: Interesting. If this were Rubinius or JRuby, I'd say it's the aggressively optimizing compiler doing its awesome job (specifically, speculative inlining), but YARV doesn't do any optimizations at all.

Comment: Algorithm-wise, you can't get any better than O(n) for finding the `min`, because you have no choice but to scan through each element.  So your solution is actually optimal.  I'm guessing that in the Ruby method, there are some additional steps that cause theirs to take a bit longer.

Comment: It's `Enumerable#min` actually, not `Array#min`. Therefore, the built-in implementation has to use `each` as well.

Comment: @Stefan I suspected that, but could've imagined some optimization for arrays. Or being faster because implemented in C. In any case, I'd still expect it to not be that much **slower**.

Comment: @dwenzel Yes, I know it's optimal that way, I'm just surprised that me writing it on a rather high level is faster, and so much faster, than the built-in. I could maybe **somewhat** understand it if it were some obscure method that simply nobody cares about, but `min`? And I can imagine additional steps needed for generality, but I'd expect them to be some case detection before the actual search, and since my array is fairly large, I'd expect that to not play a noticeable role. So apparently there's some extra cost for each array element, and it's even higher than running that block of mine.

Comment: I was curious if the same result would apply to [Enumerable#minmax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax). Using your benchmark I found the obvious custom method was 19% faster than `minmax`. I then considered [Enumerable#min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by). Again, I used your benchmark to compare `array.min_by { |i| 2*i }` with a custom `my_min_by` that yielded to the same block. The core method was 11% faster. You may want to report your findings to the Ruby monks, though I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the implementation of [Enumerable#min](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L1491). It might use `each` eventually to loop through the elements and get the min element, but before that it does some extra checking to see if it needs to return more than one element, or if it needs to compare the elements via a passed block. In your case the elements will get to be compared via [min_i](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L1429) function, and I suspect that's where the speed difference comes from - that function will be slower than simply comparing two numbers.

There's no extra optimization for arrays, all enumerables are traversed the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I still would've expected presumably compiled C to be much faster than my presumably interpreted Ruby. But looking at that `min_i` function I see `OPTIMIZED_CMP(i, memo->min, memo) < 0`, and if I change my own implementation to use `min = n if (n <=> min) < 0`, then it at least becomes *slower* than the built-in (about 8% in my test). I guess I'll leave it at that and just mourn that if I want it fast, I have to do it myself with my "long" way...

Answer (score 2):

It's even faster if you use:

```
def my_min(ary)
  the_min = ary[0]
  i = 1
  len = ary.length
  while i < len
    the_min = ary[i] if ary[i] < the_min
    i += 1
  end
  the_min
end
```

**NOTE**

I know this is not an answer, but I thought it was worth sharing and putting this code into a comment would have been exceedingly ugly.

Answer (score 1):

For those who likes to upgrade to newer versions of software

```
require 'benchmark'
array = (1..100000).to_a.shuffle

Benchmark.bmbm(5) do |x|
  x.report("lib:") { 99.times { min = array.min } }
  x.report("own:") { 99.times { min = array[0]; array.each { |n| min = n if n < min } } }
end

Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
lib:    0.021326   0.000017   0.021343 (  0.021343)
own:    0.498233   0.001024   0.499257 (  0.499746)
-------------------------------- total: 0.520600sec

            user     system      total        real
lib:    0.018126   0.000000   0.018126 (  0.018139)
own:    0.492046   0.000000   0.492046 (  0.492367)

RUBY_VERSION # => "2.7.1"
```

If you are looking into solving this in really performant manner: O(log(n)) or O(n), look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Incremental_sorting_by_selection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: Not sure why you're pointing out those other things, but yes, nice to see the library's version is now much faster :-)